# pgfkeys and passing argument with math-ish format

Tags: pgfkeys, pgf-pie

It seems that pgfkeys is attempting to do math on one of my arguments, and failing because it's not actually math.  How do I prevent this, and ensure that the argument is passed correctly?

Compiling using lualatex.  The log records a single `Missing number, treated as zero.` and then

`` Package PGF Math Error: You've asked me to divide `1' by `', but I cannot divide any number by `' (in '(0) + (1/, 1/A, 1/-1 B, 1/-2 C,)'). ``

I have tried several variations on putting {} around things, and in place of empty text, and so forth.  It might be related to the `sum=auto`, but just typing the text in does work, so something is still changing in pgfkeys.

MWE below:

```
\documentclass[twoside,headings,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}

\begin{document}

\pgfkeys{
    /TestExample/.is family, TestExample,
    % Here are the options that a user can pass
    default/.style = {
            TestPie = {},
        },
    TestPie/.store in = \TestPie,
}
\newcommand{\TestExample}[2][]{
    \clearpage
    \pgfkeys{TestExample, default, #1}%

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \pie[color=white, hide number, text=inside, sum=auto, rotate=90, change direction]{
            1/,
            1/A,
            1/-1 B,
            1/-2 C
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \pie[color=white, hide number, text=inside, sum=auto, rotate=90, change direction]{
            \TestPie
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}

    #2
}

\TestExample[TestPie={
            1/,
            1/A,
            1/-1 B,
            1/-2 C
        }]{
    Blah Blah Blah
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: pgf-pie doesn't like the comma after the C, and it doesn't like it if you hide the numbers inside `\TestPie`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer,  Are you sure?  It quite happily handles the comma after the C in the first example, where it is typed directly into the `pie` command.
And of course, the question is how to make `\TestPie` work, or to work around whatever limitation is breaking it.

Comment: yes I'm sure. And how do you know that it handles the comma? your example mixes everything together you can't actually know which part error when.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, Well, I was going to say "because it works", but you are correct, that does actually cause errors.  

Still though, the problem stands, even with the last comma removed.  I will edit the example to reflect that.

Comment: Try using `\expanded{\unexpanded{\pie[<your options>]}\expandafter}\expandafter{\TestPie}` instead.

Comment: @Skillmon, that works perfectly.  You should promote that to answer so I can mark it solved.

Comment: Alternatively, you could apply `/pgf/foreach/expand list=true` for your `\pie`.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel, That is an even better answer.  You should make it an answer so people can find it easier.

Comment: @Tetragramm I have *expand*ed the comment to a full answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `\TestPie` will be put in the place of a list, as in

```
\foreach \foo/\bar in {\TestPie} {<body>}
```

and since the first (and only) element of the list, `\TestPie`, doesn't contain a `/` it will let both `\foo` and `\bar` to `\TestPie`.

The first one will be thrown in PGFMath at some point which tries to evaluate the expansion of `\TestPie` – PGFMath always fully expands the formula – which *does* contain a `/` and PGFMath tries to divide … things.

You need to expand `\TestPie` at least once.

The least complex way to do this would be

```
\def\temp{\pie[color=white, hide number, text=inside,
               sum=auto, rotate=90, change direction]}
\expandafter\temp\expandafter{\TestPie}
```

The other answer shows a few e-TeX powered approaches.

---

However, you can also delegate the expansion to the internal `\foreach` loop by enabling

```
/pgf/foreach/expand list
```

which will lead PGFFor to *fully* expand *all* lists before iterating over them – or at least those that are used by `\pie` when it is given to the optional argment of `\pie`:

```
\pie[color=white, hide number, text=inside,
    sum=auto, rotate=90, change direction, /pgf/foreach/expand list]
{\TestPie}
```

---

This is not safe for fragile commands like `\textbf` inside the labels of the pie pieces.

But allow me to extend `expand list` so it does accepts – besides `true` and `false` – also `once` and then you can do

```
\pie[color=white, hide number, text=inside,
     sum=auto, rotate=90, change direction, /pgf/foreach/expand list=once]
{\TestPie}
```

pretty safely.

(Yes, this will expand the first token of every PGFFor loop that's used in `\pie`.)

### Code

```
\documentclass[twoside,headings,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}
\makeatletter
\pgfqkeys{/pgf/foreach/expand list}{
  .code=\csname pgffor@expand@list@#1\endcsname,
  .default=true}
\def\pgffor@expand@list@once{%
  \def\pgffor@expand@list##1{%
    \expandafter\def\expandafter##1\expandafter}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\pgfkeys{
  /TestExample/.is family, TestExample,
  % Here are the options that a user can pass
  default/.style = {
          TestPie = {},
      },
  TestPie/.store in = \TestPie,
}
\newcommand{\TestExample}[2][]{%
  \clearpage
  \pgfkeys{TestExample, default, #1}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
      \pie[color=white, hide number, text=inside,
           sum=auto, rotate=90, change direction]{
          1/,
          1/A,
          1/-1 B,
          1/-2 C
      }
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
      \def\temp{\pie[color=white, hide number, text=inside,
                     sum=auto, rotate=90, change direction]}
      \expandafter\temp\expandafter{\TestPie}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
      \pie[color=white, hide number, text=inside,
          sum=auto, rotate=90, change direction, /pgf/foreach/expand list=once]
      {\TestPie}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  #2}

\TestExample[
  TestPie={
    1/,
    1/A,
    1/-1 B,
    1/-2 \textbf{C}
  }]{Blah Blah Blah}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just for clarification (minor nitpicking): `\expanded` is not e-TeX but a primitive of the major engines. Else really good analysis of what's going wrong why, +1.

Answer (score 3):

You need to expand the value of `\TestPie` before `pgf-pie` tries to parse its argument. As an idiom you can use

```
\expanded{\unexpanded{<stuff>}\expandafter}
```

to use one step of expansion before `<stuff>` is considered. That can be used to expand your macro once.

If this is needed multiple times or you want it to be more semantically clear you can define a macro:

```
\newcommand\expandafterthings[1]{\expanded{\unexpanded{#1}\expandafter}}
```

So your call to `\pie` could look like the following:

```
\expandafterthings
  {\pie[color=white, hide number, text=inside, sum=auto, rotate=90, change direction]}\expandafter{\TestPie}
```

If you know that `\TestPie` and all your options are safe against a full expansion you could also use

```
\expanded{\noexpand\pie[<options>]{\TestPie}}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer below uses the [wheelchart](https://ctan.org/pkg/wheelchart) package, which I wrote.

The described issue does not occur in the answer below.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{wheelchart}
\begin{document}
\pgfkeys{
  /TestExample/.is family,
  TestExample,
  % Here are the options that a user can pass
  default/.style={TestPie={},},
  TestPie/.store in=\TestPie,
}
\newcommand{\TestExample}[2][]{%
%\clearpage
\pgfkeys{TestExample,default,#1}%
\pgfkeys{
  /wheelchart,
  data=,
  pie,
  slices style={
    fill=none,
    draw
  },
  wheel data=\WCvarB
}%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\wheelchart{1/,1/A,1/-1 B,1/-2 C}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\wheelchart{\TestPie}
\end{tikzpicture}
#2}
\TestExample[TestPie={1/,1/A,1/-1 B,1/-2 \textbf{C}}]{Blah Blah Blah}
\end{document}
```